# Download url obtained from file metadata using access token not working for Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Followed the steps given in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get and I am getting the download url for the particular file in google drive. But when trying that link a blank page is shown no file is getting downloaded. The get request I have used is given below

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[file_id]?fields=downloadUrl&key=[Google_api_key] 
headers
Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

Any help will be truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: We need the python code to know what's going on, A raw request won't suffice.

Comment: response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[file_id]?fields=downloadUrl&key=[Google_api_key]',  headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " +['access_token']})

response.json()

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [MediaIoBaseDownload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

```
file_id = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M'
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

I also recommend using google drive api v3 not v2